# HTML5 libraries using canvas to create hex tiles?

Tags: library, javascript, game-development

I am making a strategy game in HTML and JavaScript. I want to divide my map up into hexagonal tiles. This (the game) is for my mobile phone. I want a JavaScript library that is built on raw JavaScript that can create a hexagonal map.